# How to solve a fixed position of mobile application using HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am designing a form for mobile application using HTML and CSS. The form has a registration page which contains several text fields. The header and footer positions are fixed.

My problem is when I click on a particular text field (given `onfocus` functionality to the field) and scroll the page, the screen moves up within the header and footer as they are fixed but the selected field alone goes top of the header. I don't understand why this is happening when the selected text field alone goes up and the rest of the form sculls inside the header.

The below image illustrates my problem:

[image: Problem of mobile]

When I select the username text box and scroll up, this field alone goes up to the header and the other fields are scrolling within the header and footer.

Note: here the header and footer are kept fixed.

**Updated Code**

```
<body>
<div style="background: #000;height: 60px;position: fixed;  padding: 0 10px;width: 96%;z-index: 9999;" id="header-wrap">
    <header class="center">
<h1 id="logo">
<a href="/">My App</a>
</h1>
<h2 class="mob-usrname" style="display:none;">Mark</h2>
</header>
</div>
<section id="main" class="tabs">
<div class="page-wrap">
<h2>Register</h2>
<form class="form" method="post">
<p>
<label for="id_first_name">First name</label>
<input id="id_first_name" class="textinput" type="text" maxlength="30" value="Dan" name="first_name">
<span class="helptext"></span>
</p>
<p>
<label for="id_last_name">Last name</label>
<input id="id_last_name" class="textinput" type="text" maxlength="30" value="Hibma" name="last_name">
<span class="helptext"></span>
</p>
 <p>
<label for="id_email">E-mail address</label>
                <input id="id_email" class="textinput" type="text" maxlength="75" value="mymail@mail.com" name="email">
<span class="helptext"></span>
</p>
<p>
<label for="id_password1">Password</label>
<input id="id_password1" class="textinput" type="password" name="password1">
<span class="helptext"></span>
 </p>
 <p>
<label for="id_password2">Password Confirmation</label>
<input id="id_password2" class="textinput" type="password" name="password2">
<span class="helptext">Enter the same password as above, for verification.</span>
</p>
<p>
<label for="id_phone">Phone</label>
<input id="id_phone" class="textinput" type="text" maxlength="20" value="257-635-4735" name="phone">
<span class="helptext"></span>
</p>
<p>
<label for="id_button">Button</label>
<input id="id_button" class="textinput" type="text" maxlength="32" value="sample" name="button" readonly="readonly">
<span class="helptext"></span>
 </p>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Save">
 </form>
 </div>
</section>
<div style="background:#2C2C2C;bottom: 0;display: block !important;height: 60px;line-height: 60px;position: fixed;width: 100%;" class="mobile-footer" style="display:none">
<ul>
<li class="sam">
<a href="/">
<span></span>
<em>My Footer</em>
</a>
 </li>
<li class="mobile-sample sample">
<a href="/sample/logs">
 <span></span>
<em>logs</em>
 </a>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>   
</body>
```

Comment: its imposibble to tell what you are doing without seeing code. you know that right?

Comment: @btevfik updated my code please review now

Answer (score 2):

Your page structure for *Jquery Mobile* should be like the below.

```
<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Page Title</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">
    <p>Page content goes here.</p>
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->

 </div><!-- /page -->
```

Comment: @sathya if you are using _Jquery Mobile_, your page structure should be like the above. Put your form inside `content` div.

Answer (score 0):

See below example

```
 <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
     <div style="font-size:25px; background:#96F; position:fixed; width:100%;"> HEADER HERE </div>
     <div style="font-size:20px; background:#CCC;">
    MIDDDLES HERE <br />
           <br />
           <br />
           <br />
           <br />MIDDDLES HERE<br />MIDDDLES HERE<br />MIDDDLES HERE<br />MIDDDLES HERE<br />MIDDDLES HERE<br />MIDDDLES HERE<br />MIDDDLES HERE<br />

   </div>
   <div style="font-size:25px; background:#99F; position:fixed; width:100%; bottom:0; "> <br />FOOTER HERE <br /></div>
```

Comment: _Jquery Mobile_ is different than desktop webpage design. This won't fix the problem.

Comment: Main base is css and html and that will be same whatever language is used if there is different then just about syntax at least you can get idea.

Comment: @sathya Now, it fixed both header and footer just scrolling middle content(i.e. form).

Comment: yes both header and footer are fixed as you said middle content will gets scroll inside the header and footer. but when i select a field and scroll up or down the selected field moves out from fixed position

Comment: @sathya sorry but didn't get your problem. Is there any problem to field first name and last name. i.e. overlay by header. right? or any other problem?

Comment: As i shown in above image the after selecting any textbox and scroll up the selected text box overlays the header

Comment: @sathya  Just add padding-top:42px; in page-wrape class as like below

<div style="padding-top: 42px;" class="page-wrap">

Answer (score 0):

i am not quite sure what is going on. but adding couple of `<br>` before the register header seems to help.

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/M2u8f/